# How to separate numbers from math operators with negative numbers correctly processed

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split `string input` to 2 lists in C#, using RegEx. One must contain numbers, the other mathematical operators.

For example, the string "-9+9+8" should split into ["-9", "9", "8"] and ["+", "+"]. Parentheses are handled by a separate function.

At first I tried this:

```
List<string> textSplit = Regex.Split(input, "[*/+-]").ToList();
List<string> operators = Regex.Matches(input, "[*/+-]")
                              .Cast<Match>()
                              .Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

But I still can't figure out how to handle negative values correctly.

For example, to divide "8--4"

- not into ["8", "", "4"] and ["-", "-"],
- but to ["8", "-4"] and ["-"] instead

**Update:** The closest option I have right now is `(?<=[-+\/*])-?\d|^\d` plus `(?<=\d)[-+\/*]` . Huge gratitude to **zmehall**. But the solution is still slightly incomplete.
From `string "-5+8*2/4--6"` It correctly highlights the math operators: `["+", "*", "/", "-"]`, but not quite correctly separates the numbers: `["5", "8", "2", "4", "-6"]`. Now I'm thinking about solving this problem.

**Update2:** From the phone I did not notice the answer from **Keszas**. Took part of the solution from him, the question is closed. Many thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: This you could do with a simple loop. Loop over each character, if it is a plus sign set a boolean, if its a negative set the boolean to false, and then every other character add a number that includes the sign.

Comment: Well, in general case you have to support *unary operations*: `5---4`: (note triple `-`) or `-(2 + 3) * 5`. Why not treat `-` as an operation but compute it's *priority* and *arity* (number of arguments).

Comment: Typical way is to tokenize (values, operations, parenthesis), `8 - - 4 => ("8", value), ("-", binary operation, priority = 1), ("-", unary operation, priority = 10), ("4", value)` and then run *shunting yard algorithm*, say, to build reverse polish representation or syntax tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked on this for a bit, and I think I found a solution that works (using two separate patterns).

To capture the numbers (with signs), you can use the expression `(?<=[-+\/*])-?\d|^\d`

To capture the operations, you can use the expression `(?<=\d)[-+\/*]`

Explanation:

```
(?<=[-+\/*]) : match only if there is a sign before
-? : match an optional negative sign (if above is true)
\d : match a single digit
|^\d : match the above, or if the number is the beginning of a line


(?<=\d) : match only if there is a digit before
[-+\/*] : match either `-`, `+`, `/`, `*` (only if above condition is met)
```

Please let me know if there are any issues with my solution.

Examples:

https://regex101.com/r/Kp9lCT/1

https://regex101.com/r/NGOhY3/1

Comment: Thank you very much, at first glance, just what i need. But I can only check tomorrow, we have another blackout...
I'm still quite a beginner, and did not understand how you can specify a condition on the previous character, you helped me a lot with these examples.

Comment: Close, but slightly incomplete.
From "-5+8*2/4--6" it This correctly highlights the math operators: ["+", "*", "/", "-"], 
but not quite correctly separates the numbers: ["5", "8", "2", "4", "-6"]. I'll think about how I can fix this. Thank you very much, your answer is closest to what I need. Perhaps I will make a separate function to help if I can’t find a solution in the regex.

Comment: Found the rest of the answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to do it

```
string input = "-9+9+8";
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
List<string> operators = new List<string>();

string currentNumber = string.Empty;
foreach (char c in input)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c) || c == '-' || c == '+' || c == '.')
    {
        currentNumber += c;
    }
    else if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/')
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNumber))
            numbers.Add(currentNumber);
        currentNumber = string.Empty;
        operators.Add(c.ToString());
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNumber))
    numbers.Add(currentNumber);
```

We are iterating through the characters in the input string and checking if each character is a digit, a '-', '+' or '.', which are considered to be numbers.

If it is, it's added to the current number string. If the character is a mathematical operator, the current number is added to the numbers list, current number string is cleared and operator is added to the operators list.

Comment: Did you even try your code? This results in `numbers` containing the single item `-9+9+8`.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend using https://regex101.com/ to create and expirement with regexes.
Your problem can be solved with the following two regexes:

- `(?<!--|\d)-?\d+`: matches any digit with zero or one `-` in a way that the match will not contain a `--` or `\d-\d` sequence
- `(?<=\d)[+|-]` : matches the first `+` or `-` character after a digit

Comment: `([+|=])?` will also capture the signs of the terms, which isn't the behavior OP intended.

Comment: I thought that he wanted to split `-8+8+8` up into `-8,8,8` and `+,+` anyway I forgot to add a strts with a negative number scenario te the regex, so I just added it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Partially took the answer above, partly from you. Too bad i can't give two marks as the best answer.